# Liferay Developer Studio not resolving package com.liferay.portal.upload

Tags: java, eclipse, liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I'm trying to customize the Liferay Web Forms portlet to accept a file control, and I've just about gotten everything working except for the UploadPortletRequest to handle the actual uploading of the file from the form!

I've got:

```
import com.liferay.portal.upload.UploadPortletRequestImpl;
```

and in the compiler output:

```
[javac] 1. ERROR in C:\Program Files\Liferay Developer Studio\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.0-ee-sp2-20110727\portlets\AZ_WebForms-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\src\com\liferay\autozone\webform\portlet\AZ_WebForm.java (at line 34)
[javac]     import com.liferay.portal.upload.UploadPortletRequestImpl;
[javac]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[javac] The import com.liferay.portal.upload cannot be resolved
```

BUT...If I add `portal-impl.jar` to the `Portal Dependency JARs` to be able to resolve the class, it won't compile because `portal-impl.jar` is in `WEB-INF/lib`!! (and it doesn't like that)

I'm kind of at a loss here. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use anything from portal-impl.jar, unless you use ext environment and you modify Liferay.

From your compiler output I would say that you are writing your own portlet, not customizing existing. Am I wrong?

You must handle upload your self. Yyou can use [Apache commons fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/), it supports portlets.

Pleas see [Using FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html), specifically [Servlets and portlets part](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html#Servlets_and_Portlets)

Comment: I am actually customizing existing Web Form portlet from Liferay core. I will look into Apache Commons fileupload. Thanks.